# Any suggestion on charting plugin for time stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, highcharts

I've been spending quite some time looking for a charting plugin for time tracking, ie. Engine Time Tracking chart as following image:
[image]

A bit explanation:

*green / red / gray* denotes *engine on / engine off / not available*
*horizontal axis* is the *time line for each day*
*vertical axis* is *every single day*

I am just showing an example and expecting someone here has any idea about this kind of charting plugins. I am not sure whether [HighCharts stacked bar chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked) can do that, since I want a status switching bar chart, not an accumulative one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in Flotr (which has a better license than highcharts) by just throwing what they showed in [this blog post](http://www.2general.com/blog/2012/05/30/flot_stacked_bar_chart.html) on its side.

Comment: Thanks dude. But this one is not a **time** stacked chart I want. It would be much better if I could find some charts having that function or is possible to do that. Actually I believe highCharts can do that as I see in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499822/extjs-4-time-stacked-bar-chart-possible)

Comment: So something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UDwz7/)? [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9499822)

Comment: @A T maybe not..what I want is not only the time axis, also more important it can reflect the status changing. e.x. the engine's on ->off -> on -> off, which is defined by my given time input. Actually the attached image in the question would be what I want in HighCharts. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use column range chart or stacked with datetime type of axis.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type