# How to build HighCharts bar chart from left to right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

See this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5CVk6/) example, the data series

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]  // the right most part
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]  // the middle part
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]  // the left most part
}]
```

creates the chart from right to left, I am looking for a way so that the chart can be done from left to right. Thanks!

my data:

```
[
    {
        "day": "2009-07-13",
        "work": ["11:16:35-12:03:12", "12:32:48-13:26:28", "13:39:09-13:39:12", "13:41:03-13:41:05", "14:18:09-24:00:00"]
    }, {
        "day": "2009-07-14",
        "work": ["00:00:00-07:22:25", "07:22:25-07:22:28", "10:10:04-10:10:31", "10:10:32-10:15:33", "10:18:07-10:21:19", "11:04:49-11:06:15", "11:12:50-11:19:05", "11:19:11-11:19:19", "11:45:50-11:51:42", "11:51:43-11:53:55", "14:03:13-14:13:04", "14:23:55-14:31:28", "14:31:28-14:38:00", "14:38:00-14:49:04", "16:34:56-16:44:33", "16:46:37-16:48:10", "16:48:11-24:00:00"]
    }, {
        "day": "2009-07-15",
        "work": ["00:00:00-08:16:23", "09:57:57-10:15:05"]
    }
]
```

**EDIT**: Sorry about my English and confusion, [**another jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tVnSB/7/) can better explain what I am talking about. I want to create a chart to represent my engine switch on/off status so that the **fed in data** for bar chart is from left to right, instead of right to left in the give fiddle. Thanks!

Comment: When I run your fiddle it's creating it from left to right...

Comment: Please see update, sorry for my English and confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big assumption but I think you are looking for a [Gantt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) chart.
See [this](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=19043) post on HighCharts forum for ideas.

Comment: That actually was my post....Looks like I have to go with line type chart. You have any ideas how create line type chart like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500211/javascript-jquery-library-for-gantt-like-chart) (suppose it is a bar type chart after 90 degree rotation)?

Comment: Ha. Sorry to link you to your own post. Well, I have used http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/2qfgg/7/ as a template for Gantt charts when I needed them. Why can't you apply this? Is there some particular error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks I am just about to go with this one since indeed bar type chart for gantt needs a lot data tweaking. I will get back to you soon after I play around with this. Thanks so much!

Comment: After first view of this chart, would that be possible to remove the points on the side of the bar and show tooltip on the body of the bar instead of side points?  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can use events to fire off when the mouse hovers/clicks on the span of the data.

Comment: Thanks, but since its a scatter type chart, so the scatter points cannot be removed or set invisible, is that right?

Comment: That I am not sure of but it seems that ou could of course set each series to on/off and even down to a particular point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. One more concern for me now is: Do I have to convert the datetime data (I have updated in my question) to number of milliseconds from midnight of January 1, 1970, like in the example? `"start" : 1331127220000, "end" : 1331128050000`. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Date.parse("date string") as far as I can tell (we parse it to js time before hand in SQL).

Comment: Thanks. Clarified my concern. Now still a long way for me to tweak my data. :(

Comment: just find one problem, I actually trying to plot engine on/off for different days as this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475957/any-suggestion-on-charting-plugin-for-time-stacked-bar-chart) shows. So x-axis would be different days and y-axis would be the time stamp. If I go for that example, I couldn't plot my data into the same chart. Because all the data for each day will have increasing time stamps..

Comment: Why not make you xAxis a categor (each day)? If possible can you put up a jsFiddle with what you have currently.

Comment: here is my current [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/993n4/). Yes, I want to make the category for each day. But the problem is: in the scatter chart options setting you   can see that `xAxis : { min : 1331121600000, max : 1331157600000,`, and all their data is setting as unix timestamp, so if I convert all my data (you can refer to my quesion) to unix, then they will not be in the same scale, because every different day they have different `min` and `max` for x-aixs, that's the different from the original example. I have no idea how to plot those bars in the same chart..Thanks a lot

Comment: Convert your timestamp to just hour/min/sec/whatever that is under one day in length.

Comment: sorry I did not get it. Say for "2009-07-13", and "2009-07-14", the unix `min` value of "2009-07-14" more than the unix `max` value of "2009-07-13", so I can still plot them in the same chart?

Comment: I think I get your point know and start work on it again. Thanks

Comment: Looks like there is no solution to show tooltip when mouse hovering the body of the bar? If you happen to get a solution for that, please let me know or answer the question [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530051/highcharts-tooltip-issue-for-scatter-chart). The marker has removed by `marker: {enabled: false}`. Thank you